# divide and conquer to count the number of good segments

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I have been studying divide-and-conquer for a while, and am now looking into the following problem:

> Given a permutation P of length N, count the number of good segments. Note that a sequence A of N integers is called a permutation of length N if:
>
> 1≤ A<sub>i</sub> ≤ N for all 1 ≤ i ≤ N, and A<sub>i</sub> != A<sub>j</sub> for all 1 ≤ i != j ≤ N.
>
> A continuous segment [l, r] of a permutation P is *good* if the value of (P<sub>l</sub>, P<sub>l+1</sub>, ..., P<sub>r</sub>) is also continuous. That is, if we collect P<sub>l</sub>, P<sub>l+1</sub>, ..., P<sub>r</sub> into a new list B and sort it, then this will hold:
>
> B<sub>1</sub> = B<sub>2</sub>−1, B<sub>2</sub> = B<sub>3</sub>−1, ..., B<sub>i-1</sub> = B<sub>i</sub>−1, ..., B<sub>|B|−1</sub> = B<sub>|B|</sub>−1.
>
> For example, in the permutation [3, 2, 4, 5], there are 8 good segments:
>
> [3], [2], [4], [5], [3,2], [4,5], [3,2,4], and [3,2,4,5]

I analysed several cases when combining two small divided arrays, but I cannot think of a strategy that can detect good segments that cross two separate arrays in *O(N)* time.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't think it is possible to apply divide-and-conquer in efficient way here.

You need to inspect `O(n^2)` substrings of a given permutation. You may apply divide-and-conquer for example by dividing the array into 2 halves (left and right), inspect all substrings starting in the left half and ending in the right half, then call left and right halves recursively.  This is going to give:

`n/2 * n/2 = (n/2)^2 = (n^2)/4` substrings on level 1

`n/4 * n/4 + n/4 * n/4 = 2 * (n/4)^2 = (n^2)/8` substrings on level 2

`n/8 * n/8 + n/8 * n/8 + n/8 * n/8 + n/8 * n/8 = 4 * (n/8)^2 = (n^2)/16` substrings on level 3, and so on

This asymptotically yields `O(n^2 * log n)` substrings to be analyzed, worse than `O(n^2)` substrings if we just process them iteratively

For the number of subproblems larger than 2, things are not better: if we split into 3, complexity is `O(n^2 * log3n)`, and so on